# Wondering why my ArrayList won't print?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I'm trying to print my ArrayList, AList which is an ArrayList of type Question (a class I've created myself) and I'm using the toString method but it doesn't seem to be working. It's still printing the array address.

```
for(int i = 0; i < AList.size(); i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(AList.get(i).toString());
    }
```

The get(i) gets the Question objects in the ArrayList.
I've tried it like:

```
System.out.println(AList.toString());
```

as well. And it just never seems to work.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Not sure if this is too vague. I'm rather new to Java.

Thanks so much!!

Also, it seems as though my compiler's telling me I can't pass arguments to the toString method. :(

Comment: Please show your whole code.  Are the elements of the `ArrayList` themselves arrays?

Comment: Looks like AList.get(i) is an Object. So you have to implement toString() method for that object.

Comment: So what output do you get? Or no output at all?

Comment: AList is an ArrayList of what type?

Comment: The type which is returned by `AList.get(i)` should override `toString()`. Then only it would print the string representation of your list.

Comment: Does your `Question` class have a `toString()` method? Have you tested that method to make sure it works?

Answer (score 0):

1.Is AList's size zero?

2.`toString()` will print classname if U haven't `override` the `toString()` of `Object` in `List`;

Answer (score 0):

By default all object in java return hex value when calling toString function please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

If you want some meaningful value from toString you have to override it like below

```
Class Question {
    String text;
    ...
    @Override
     public String toString() { 
         return this.text;
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like below .

First you need to check AList.size().

```
if(AList.size() == 0){
 System.out.println("AList.size() == 0");

}else{

for(int i = 0; i < AList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(AList.get(i));
}
}
```

And you can override toString() method in your Question Object.

```
public String toString() {
  return "Question: " + questionname+ ", and Question Answer" + questionanswer;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use generics:

```
ArrayList<Question> Alist = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now when you call Alist.get(i), it will return the Question Object and override the below method as told by user KishuDroid

```
public String toString()
```

This method is called when you try to print any object. So in this method you should return the string what you want to print when calling

```
System.out.println(Alist.get(i));
```

Alist.toString() will print the address of Alist object.